# When is $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d \setminus \{ 0 \})$ dense in $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $d\in \mathbb N$. Under what constraints for $d$ and $p$  is $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d \setminus \{ 0 \})$ dense in $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ with respect to the $L^p(\mathbb R^d)$-norm?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $b_n$ be a sequence of smooth functions $b_n: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ such that $b_n(x) = 1$ for $|x|> { 2\over n}$ and $b_n(x) = 0$ for $|x|< {1 \over n}$.

If $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$, then $b_n\cdot f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d \setminus \{0\})$ and for $p< \infty$ we have $\|f-b_n \cdot f\|_p \to 0$.

If $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ such that $f(0) = 1$, then we must have
$\|f-g\|_\infty \ge 1$ for any $g \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d \setminus \{0\})$.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure that your question makes sense, since the first set is not a subset of the second. I don't think you can embed it in any reasonable way, since it is not always possible to extend a continuous function from the first set to the other. I'd guess for $d=1$, something like $sin(1/x)$ smoothed out to some compact domain should be an example.

Edit: I guess setting $f(0)=0$ should work as an embedding, since any compact set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ should have empty intersection with some ball around $0$.

Comment: It is contained in the other. The important thing is that the functions are compactly supported in $\mathbb{R}^d\setminus \{0\}$, ie the function is zero in a nbhd of the origin and thus can extended smoothly by zero.

Comment: For $U \subset \Bbb{R}^n$, $C^\infty_c(U)$ means  the smooth functions on $\Bbb{R}^n$ supported on some compact $\subset U$